# Nested_form gem with edit functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems

I'm looking for a  rails gem with nested_form which includes the functionality to edit the created object, for example given a project with its associated tasks I want to have the possibility to select one or many tasks and edit them instead of remove then add new tasks.

Our app currently use Cocoon gem but it doesn't seem to include this functionality.

Exemple :

[image]

Bottom text is add, duplicate, remove and edit links

Don't care about the orange box

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities, and both come from the same place (even though I didn't try the second one)

[The first one](https://www.driftingruby.com/episodes/nested-forms-from-scratch) is to build your own nested form (what I did), I promise you that you'll be able to edit the nested form without deleting / recreating it. However, I suggest you'll create a side project to train, just to be sure you won't do regretable mistakes

**[EDIT]** My bad, I didn't see you tried Cocoon already